# Problem occurs during code execution of setInterval loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a weird issue developping a 2D game in Angular.

the function in my component call an async function to load the sprites, then execute the game loop in the callback GameComponent.ts:

```
  constructor(private loader: AppService, private game: GameService, private 
              score: ScoreService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loader.createGameEnvironment(this.canvas.nativeElement);
    this.subscribed = this.loader.getAssetsLoadedEmitter().subscribe(() => {
      this.game.startGame();
      this.lastScore = this.game.score;
      console.log(this.userScore._id);
    });
    console.log(this.userScore._id);
    if (this.userScore._id !== undefined) {
      this.userScore.score = this.lastScore;
      this.score.updateScore(this.userScore).subscribe( () => {
        console.log('score updated successfully: ' + this.userScore.score);
      });
    } else {
      this.showModal = true;
    }
  }
```

the function in my game service class which define the game loop GameService.ts:

```
  startGame(): void {
    this.score = 0;
    /* launch the loop every 10 miliseconds */
    this.gameLoop = setInterval(() => {
      this.suffleProperties();
      this.cleanCanvas();
      this.renderBackground();
      this.createObstacles();
      this.moveObstacles();
      this.createPlayer();
      this.updateScore();
      console.log(this.score);
    }, 10);
    // window.location.reload();
  }
```

the function which call the clearInterval GameService.ts:

```
  checkCollision(obstacle: Obstacles): void {
    if (((this.player.x + CONFIG.playerCar.width > obstacle.x) && (this.player.y < obstacle.y + obstacle.height)) &&
        ((this.player.x < obstacle.x + obstacle.width) && (this.player.y < obstacle.y + obstacle.height)) &&
        ((this.player.x + CONFIG.playerCar.width > obstacle.x) && (this.player.y + CONFIG.playerCar.height > obstacle.y)) &&
        ((this.player.x < obstacle.x + obstacle.width) && (this.player.y + CONFIG.playerCar.height > obstacle.y))) {
      clearInterval(this.gameLoop);
      alert('Game Over');

    }
  }
```

the entry point of the  call the checkCollision function GameService.ts:

```
  moveObstacles(): void {
    this.obstacles.forEach((element: Obstacles, index: number) => {
      element.y += 3;
      element.update();
      this.checkCollision(element);
      if (element.y > this.height) {
        this.obstacles.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

Definition of the EventEmitter where we load the game in the callback in the component:

```
export class AppService {

isAssetsLoaded: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private game: GameService) { }

  createGameEnvironment(canvasElement): void {
    this.game.loadSpritesAssets(canvasElement).then( () => {
      this.isAssetsLoaded.emit();
    });
  }

  getAssetsLoadedEmitter(): EventEmitter<number> {
    return this.isAssetsLoaded;
  }
```

the problem is when the clearInterval is reached and the loop finish the code execution doesn't go out of the startGame method and i can't reach the code part outside the subscription in the AfterViewInit inside the component.

Comment: Can you please describe your problem a bit more precisely? I don't really understand what's exactly your problem, do you want to continue the program's execution in the ngOnInit? But it continues right after you create the startGame loop...

Comment: Well knowing setInterval method is asynchronous, actually my code outside the subscribe is called one time at execution then the thread go in the subscribe and call the startGame method. The real problem i'm facing is when the game finish and the clearInterval is called, i want to go back in the component to reach the code outside the subscribe in the ngAfterViewInit to update or create the score of the user in the DB but this part of code is never reached back after the game execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for your problem: [updated stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq4y95?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I have created an EventEmitter, to which you can subscribe, in order to get the final score.

in the game.service.ts:

```
export interface IGameEndData{
  message: string;
  score: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class GameService {
 gameEndEvent = new EventEmitter<IGameEndData>();

 checkCount(): void {
    if (this.count === 10) {
      clearInterval(this.gameLoop);
      console.log('Game Over');
      this.gameEndEvent.emit({
        message: "You can put any kind of information in here",
        score: this.score
      })
...
```

and in the app.component.ts:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loader.createGameEnvironment(this.canvas.nativeElement);
    this.subscribed = this.loader.getAssetsLoadedEmitter().subscribe(() => {
      this.game.startGame();

      this.game.gameEndEvent.subscribe((endData:IGameEndData)=>{
        console.log("endData: ", endData);
        console.log("setting the current score as last score:");
        this.lastScore.score = endData.score;
        console.log("last score object:", this.lastScore);
      })
```

Hope this is something you wanted to.

Comment: Well i was thinking actually about this solution the problem that the entry point of the game is like you see in the ngAfterViewInit, but all of the others functions are within the service, your solution would occurs some Circular dependency warnings.

Comment: In that case, could you please create a stackblitz example (https://stackblitz.com/)? It would be easier for me to help, if you could create a minimal, verifiable example. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: editor link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-43zskv - appLink: https://angular-43zskv.stackblitz.io

Comment: @GuillaumeD did you have the time to take a look at the updated answer?

Comment: Thanks for reply i tested your solution who is working well, i found on my side another solution pretty similar i return a promise in my startGame function where i set the execution of the gameLoop in the internal execution of the promise and if the game is done i call the resolve function who send the score who is recovered in the then part called in the ngAfterViewInit where i make the score creation or update